# Is there a hack/trick to enable local kernel debugging on Windows 7 x64

Tags: debugging, kernel, windbg, local

I'm kind of surprised that this has been deprecated.
I have tried to boot with "Debugging Mode" in the Windows 7 Boot Menu (i.e. F8 early in the boot process).

Wasn't sure if this question belongs here or in SuperUser.com, but figured it was still pretty much Dev oriented...

Answer (score 2):

Just [use LiveKD instead](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897415). It gives you the same features as local kernel debugging plus a few added benefits, such as not needing debugging enabled.

-scott

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using BCDEdit to setup a separate entry with debugging enabled.  See the following article for more details.  Or let me know if you have any questions.

[Boot Parameters for Kernel Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff542279%28VS.85%29.aspx)